# How to index field of embedded document

Tags: orientdb

I have class `User` with embedded class `Social`. `Social` has properties `vk`,`fb`, so my structure something like:

```
User {
   @class: User
   social: {
        @class : Social
        "vk":"123",
        "fb":"456"
    }
}
```

How to create index, that i can use it on select: `select from User where social.vk = '123'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indexes are created for properties of class, not for embedded ones, so it's not possible.

We can create two separate class `User` and `Social` and indexes:

```
create class User
create class Social

create property Social.vk string
create property User.social LINK Social

create index User.social unique
create index Social.vk unique
```

Now `select from User where social.vk = '123'` uses index

Let me know, if I'm wrong.